# Laravel - Mostrar columna oculta desde el controlador

Tags: laravel

Estoy teniendo un problema, tengo mi modelo utilizando `$hidden` lo cual esta bien para el 97% de los casos.

```
protected $hidden = ['user_id'];
```

En ocaciones especiales, necesito traer este campo `(user_id)`, actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente manera:
Controller:

```
$curseParent = Curse::where('id', $request->curse_id)->first();
```

El cual me devuelve información exitosa, pero sin `user_id` como digo, en ocaciones muy especiales lo necesito.

¿Hay alguna manera de traer las columnas ocultas directamente desde el controlador?
Cabe decir que ya he utilizado `->select('user_id')->first();` el cual tampoco me devuelve el dato.

Comment: probá hacer la query con Query Builder en vez de con el modelo. `$curseParent = DB::table('curses')->where('id', $request->curse_id)->first();`

Comment: Estoy trabajando con Eloquent, tu respuesta me funciona sin embargo busco la manera más limpia con su ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [makeVisible()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HidesAttributes.html#method_makeVisible).
Hará que los atributos dados, aunque los hayas marcado como ocultos en el modelo, sean visibles.

```
$curseParent = Curse::where('id', $request->curse_id)->first();
$curseParent->makeVisible('user_id')->toArray();
```

nota que primero deberás instanciar el modelo para luego aplicarle este método.

De la [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

> Si desea que algunos atributos típicamente ocultos sean visibles en una instancia de modelo dada, puede usar el método `makeVisible`. El método `makeVisible` devuelve la instancia del modelo para un encadenamiento de métodos conveniente.
>
> `return $user->makeVisible('attribute')->toArray();`

Comment: No intente, sin embargo no me funciono. /:

Comment: oh.. para escribir la respuesta, lo probé con el password de un usuario y me funcionó bien. Que version de Laravel usas? en versiones anteriores había un método [withHidden()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_withHidden).